# Behavior with std::erase() non-references vs reference

Tags: c++, c++17

Suppose I have a vector of type `my_object` which has a size of 3 and I want to get 3 elements from my vector storing them in a reference

Then I want to remove and erase element_3 by using `std::remove_if()` and element_1 and element_2 by using `std::remove`

Here is `my_object`:

```
  class my_object {
  public:
     my_object(int num);
     bool exists() const;
  private:
     int num;
  };
  my_object::my_object(int num) : num(num) {}
  bool my_object::exists() { return num == 1; }
```

Here is `main`:

```
  std::vector<my_object> my_vector;
  int main() {
     my_object e1(2);
     my_object e2(2);
     my_object e3(1); // i.e exists() will return true in lambda

     my_vector.push_back(e1);
     my_vector.push_back(e2);
     my_vector.push_back(e3);   

     const auto& element_1 = my_vector.at(0);
     const auto& element_2 = my_vector.at(1);
     const auto& element_3 = my_vector.at(2);

     auto lambda = [](auto& src) { return src.exists() };
     std::erase(std::remove_if(b, e, lambda), e); // remove_if for element_3
     std::erase(std::remove(b, e, element_1), e);
     std::erase(std::remove(b, e, element_2), e);   
     return 0;
  }
```

What is extremely weird is that when I declare element_1, element_2, element_3 by reference than the erasing isn't done properly and the size isn't decreased to 0, but when I write `const auto` with no `&` then it works perfectly fine, can anyone explain this weird behavior to me?

Comment: How about a *real*, [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ? I must have missed another memo (again) because I didn't know `std::erase` was even in the standard library. Also, those *references* actually *reference* the objects living in your container. A `remove_if` that possibly swaps elements isn't going to magically rehome those references.

Comment: But I tested that only element_3 get's removed using remove_if so element_1 and element_2 still hold a valid reference, it doesn't matter what I swap once a reference is initialized I could swap all indexes in my_vector and I will still reference the same value. And to prove my point I changed the order of erasing. i.e first remove() then remove_if() and still I get a size() more than 0

Comment: Your statement, "once a reference is initialized I could swap all indexes in my_vector and I will still reference the same value", is wrong. The reference is essentially a memory address, it does not stick to a value which jumps around.

Comment: Please add complete compile-able code to the question, which anyone can then run locally. It is hard to reason without a common ground such as that.

Comment: Sorry, I'm (a) searching for a duplicate, and (b) failing that, likely crafting an mcve since you apparently won't. It would help your question immensely.

Comment: My project is too huge and including everything is unnecessary I will make a complete example though.

Comment: @MosheRabaev: Stack Overflow is for specific, answerable questions; not generic debugging help. We don't want you to include everything, just enough that your example can be understood by someone else. If you haven't done the work to reduce your problem down to just a single thing that you don't understand, you are just wasting everyone's time.

Comment: @WhozCraig, I don't know if you've heard, but there's a `std::erase` in the Library Fundamentals 2 TS (not standard) for the purpose of uniform erasure (like `std::begin`, `std::end`, `std::size`, etc.)

Comment: 2 downvotes for no reason :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Discounting the methods of erasure, those references are just that: references to objects *living in the container*. Once `remove` or `remove_if` have performed their tasked move-assignment while marching up the sequence, those references are still referring to the same elements, but the occupants of those slots are:

- At best, still valid objects because a valid object either stayed where it was, or one was move-assigned there.
- Mere shells of some former self because the reference now refers to a source object that was never reclaimed by a targeted move.

I'm not going to dive into `std::remove`, Rather. Look at this rather trivial example of `std::remove_if`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
    const auto& a1 = v.at(0);
    const auto& a2 = v.at(2);
    const auto& a3 = v.at(4);

    std::cout << a1 << ' ' << a2 << ' ' << a3 << '\n';

    std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const auto& x) { return x == 3; });

    std::cout << a1 << ' ' << a2 << ' ' << a3 << '\n';
}
```

**Output**

```
1 3 5
1 4 5
```

As you can see, the functional description of [**`std::remove_if`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) lives up to what you see in the code. The `3` element was removed, and the `4` element was move-assigned to its place. What you don't see here is that the `5` element was move-assigned to the `4`'s place, and the `5` value you see here now happens to be coming from the slot where `5` *was*. The standard says that object is "valid", but with an "unspecified" value. We can verify that by ensuring our move-source of a move-assignment is, in fact, "invalid" (as far as we're concerned). Modifying our original program gives us this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct S
{
    S(int n) : value(n), isvalid(true)
    {
    }

    S(const S& s) : value(s.value), isvalid(true)
    {
    }

    S(S&& s) : value(s.value), isvalid(true)
    {
        s.isvalid = false;
    }

    S& operator =(S&& s)
    {
        value = s.value;
        isvalid = s.isvalid;

        s.isvalid = false;
        return *this;
    }

    int value;
    bool isvalid;
};

std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& outp, const S& s)
{
    outp << s.value << '(' << std::boolalpha << s.isvalid << ')';
    return outp;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<S> v = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
    const auto& a1 = v.at(0);
    const auto& a2 = v.at(2);
    const auto& a3 = v.at(4);

    std::cout << a1 << ' ' << a2 << ' ' << a3 << '\n';

    std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const auto& x) { return x.value == 3; });

    std::cout << a1 << ' ' << a2 << ' ' << a3 << '\n';
}
```

**Output**

```
1(true) 3(true) 5(true)
1(true) 4(true) 5(false)
```

The bottom line: your references are still referring to the same slots they were before, but the elements have been either (a) move assigned to something else, or (a) no longer containing specified content. Tread carefully when using references to container contents when performing container modifications.

I reserve comment on the `std::erase` calls, as I have no idea what you're doing there at all. To my knowledge that isn't even a function in the standard library (wouldn't be the first time I missed out on a new function, but scraping over cppreference yields nothing, so take that for what its worth).

Comment: There is a std::experimental::erase in the library fundamentals TS2. But I believe that the parameters wouldn't match.